# Yumで「There was a problem importing one of the Python modules」というエラーがでる

Tags: python, centos, aws, yum

状況

Amazon Linux環境で、pythonをバージョンアップしたところ、yumが利用できなくなりました。
yum コマンドを入力すると以下のメッセージが表示されてしまいます。

```
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   No module named yum

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.6.4 (r264:75706, Mar  4 2017, 14:46:28)
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)]
```

他のサイトの情報に従い、yumのpythonのバージョンを変更してみましたが、同様のメッセージが出る状況です。

/usr/bin/yum

```
#!/usr/bin/python26
```

恐らく、yumが依存していたpythonのバージョンと異なっていると考えているのですが、yumが依存しているpythonのバージョンを知るほうほうはないでしょうか？

環境
・Amazon Linux 3.14.20-20.44.amzn1.x86_64

Comment: pythonをバージョンアップはどのように行ったのでしょうか。

Comment: @take88 ありがとうございます。 バージョンアップはソースからビルドしました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yumが依存パッケージは次のコマンドで確認できます。

`rpm -qR yum`

Comment: ありがとうございます。確認できました。

`
/usr/bin/python2.7
config(yum) = 3.4.3-137.65.amzn1
python(abi) = 2.7
python27(dist-packages)
python27-iniparse
python27-pygpgme
python27-pyliblzma
python27-pyxattr
python27-urlgrabber >= 3.9.0-8
rpm >= 0:4.4.2
rpm-python27 > 4.11.2-2.63.amzn1
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
yum-metadata-parser(python27) >= 1.1.0
`